# How does the program identifiy the end of a array pointed by a pointer and created dynamically?

Tags: c

Would you like to help me to understand the mechanism of "pointers" in C:

How does the program identify the end of an array, which was dynamically allocated and pointed at by a pointer (example: montext1)? Where are these arrays stored in RAM (probably not in data, not in stack, perhaps in the heap)?

A pointer is defined by a type and a size: how is this implemented in RAM for a dynamic allocation like in the example below?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * gettext()
{
    char *text;
    printf("Text:");
    scanf("%s", &text);
    printf("\n");
    return text;
}

int main()
{
    char *montext1 = gettext();
    char *montext2 = gettext();
}
```

Comment: The behavior of your program is undefined because you use an uninitialized pointer `text`.

Comment: This isn't going to work. gettext() needs to allocate memory. To allocate 80 characters, it could use text = malloc(80);

Comment: Seriously, who up-voted this question?

Answer (score 1):

Your program is very wrong, and has undefined behavior. So it's not a very good starting point for discussion.

There is no "dynamic allocation" in your program, only chaotic overwriting of random memory.

It *should* use heap allocation, i.e.:

```
char * gettext(void)
{
  char *s;

  printf("Text:");
  fflush(stdout);
  if((s = malloc(256)) != NULL)
  {
    if(fgets(s, 256, stdin) == NULL)
    {
      free(s);
      s = NULL;
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```

The caller must `free()` the returned string, and check for `NULL` before printing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the CPU does not know the end of the data pointed to by a pointer. For the CPU it's just raw bytes in the memory which can be either application bytes or data entered by the user. However the compiled C code via the C std library know the string (`char*`) is supposed to end with a zero byte. That's how it knows where the end is.

But, in the `gettext` method: you need to allocate some memory too, via `malloc` (`calloc`), because in it's current stage your application is writing into memory which is not owned by it. And of course, the caller of `gettext` needs to `free` the memory.

And finally: a pointer is just an address in the memory, it points to some bytes. It is the role of the application to interpret those bytes in the proper way, such as identify zero terminated strings.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the program identify the end of an array, which was dynamically allocated and pointed at by a pointer

This is handled internally by the dynamic memory allocation library routines and it is handled differently on every implementation. The actual code could be in `stdlib` or it could be in an OS API. So how it is done depends on compiler and OS both.

> Where are these arrays stored in RAM

If they were dynamically allocated, they were stored on the heap.

> A pointer is defined by a type and a size

No, a pointer is a type, end of story.

> how is this implemented in RAM for a dynamic allocation like in the example below

You linked no example containing dynamic allocation. The code you posted is nonsense code. It attempts to copy data into the address where you allocated a pointer. This doesn't make any sense, so the program will crash and burn.

If you rewrite the program so that `scanf("%s", &text);` is replaced by `scanf("%s", text);`, then you attempt to copy data into an uninitialized pointer's address, which is random. This is undefined behavior and will also cause your program to crash and burn.